# Can the U.S. president increase toilet paper supplies?

Tags: united-states, president, economy

I saw a recent news article about President Trump, forcing car makers to make [ventilators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ventilator).

In the US there also a significant shortage of toilet paper, which seem to be a supply and demand problem.  People want more than the available supply.

Can the president increase toilet paper supplies?

Comment: The question might seem a bit frivolous but it's a substantive question about what the POTUS can do in the economy in an emergency. I'd object to having it closed.

Comment: Is there actually a toilet paper problem? Over here it's been a local distribution problem only, caused by increased demand due to scenes of possible shortages abroad.

Comment: @JJforTransparencyandMonica What I've read is that [the shortages are just local ones due to hoarding](https://www.opb.org/news/article/covid19-coronavirus-disrupts-supply-chains-toilet-paper-portland-state-university-professor/) and there's no long term lack of toilet paper

Comment: It's really a self-correcting problem.  Unlike for instance ventilators, where there's a real need for more, the use of toilet paper is pretty well constant: if some people panic and buy more, that just means they will be buying less for the foreseeable future.

Comment: Toilet-related questions? What do you think this is, [Travel.SE](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1431/324)?

Comment: @divibisan thanks that is a really good info in the link you supplied.  But the shortages are more then just local.  Do to the lock down, many have changed to online supplies.  Currently, there are no reputable source for acquiring TP online.  They all report out of stock with messages like "We don't know when or if this item will be back in stock." In the few place where it may be possible to order it, most are offering delivery in weeks or months from time of order.

Comment: Unless you are willing to break isolation to venture to the store, on the off chance there will be TP supplies, there is no reliable source.  I would not say that there are local shortages, the shortage is widespread, there may be local supplies, if you can find them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

President Trump was able to do that with ventilators because of the [Defense Production Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_Production_Act_of_1950#COVID-19):

> On March 18, 2020, in response to the COVID-19 outbreak, President Trump issued an executive order that defined ventilators and protective equipment as "essential to the national defense", the standard required by the DPA.[17][18] Later that day, he indicated that he would not make immediate use of DPA authority, writing, "Hopefully there will be no need"; he indicated that he would do so in a "worst-case scenario".[19][20] Speaker of the House Nancy Pelosi called upon Trump to "immediately use the powers of the DPA to mass produce and coordinate distribution of" critically needed hospital equipment such as ventilators, swabs, and personal protective equipment.[19][20] On March 20, Trump said that he will use the DPA.[21] General Motors (GM) CEO Mary Barra spoke to Trump administration officials about how GM could support production of ventilators.[22] On March 23, Trump issued an executive order classifying "health and medical resources necessary to respond to the spread of COVID-19" as subject to the authority granted by DPA to prohibit hoarding and price gouging.[23][24] Trump's continued reluctance to use the act's authorities prompted further criticism.[25] On March 27, 2020, after negotiations with GM to produce ventilators had broken down over cost, which was being estimated at over $1 billion, but primarily due to GM’s uncertainty as to its ability to provide the number of ventilators required speedily, Trump ordered HHS Secretary Alex Azar to use the authority available under the DPA to require GM to accept and prioritize contracts for the number of ventilators that Azar determines to be appropriate.[26] Trump also named Peter Navarro national policy coordinator for the DPA.[27]

For Trump to do this for toilet paper, he would need to declare it vital to national defense. That seems kind of silly to me, but I recon he *could* do that. It has been done for "aerospace structures":

> In June 13, 2017, President Donald Trump invoked the law to classify as "critical to national defense" two sets of products. The first referenced "items affecting aerospace structures and fibers, radiation-hardened microelectronics, radiation test and qualification facilities, and satellite components and assemblies".[13][14]

Answer (score 1):

There is no real shortage of toilet paper *production*, though hoarding is going on at the *distribution* end, reinforced by media coverage of toilet paper issues.

The president may or may not have the levers to *increase supply/production*, I defer to other answers there.  But perhaps a more relevant response, given that there is no shortage, would be *rationing*.

However, it's not all that difficult to make the argument that the president, and politicians elsewhere, have bigger fish to fry right now than chasing after a largely inexistent problem.

Also the advent of official, government-led, rationing, on any general goods, in itself would trigger additional worries and panic so it should only be done if there is a real need for it.  Informally, supermarkets are already starting to ask customers to limit hoarding-type purchases.

Comment: In 1973 [Johnny Carson](https://www.snopes.com/fact-check/johnny-carson-tp-shortage/) incited hording and caused a short lived toilet paper shortage.